# Best way for U.S. citizen to obtain China visa while in Europe?

Tags: visas, europe, china, us-citizens

For a U.S. citizen who is travelling in Europe and wants to fly from Europe to China, what is the recommended way to obtain a Chinese visa?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Chinese Emabassy in the UK](http://www.chinese-embassy.org.uk/eng/visa/) site refers visa applications to the [Chinese Visa Application Service Center](http://www.visaforchina.org/). According to this site, they have locations in London, Manchester, Stockholm, Gothenburg, Copenhagen, The Hague, Brussels, Paris, Marseilles, Milan, Rome and Madrid.

The terms of their online application state that applicants must be a citizen or resident of the country where the application is made.

> ordinary passport holders who are UK citizens and citizens of other
>   countries possessing UK permanent residence or work permits

However, you may be able to make an application in person at one of these locations or at a Chinese embassy or consulate in Europe. As [others](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/thread.jspa?threadID=1861749) have reported success doing this.

> At the consulate in Goteborg, Sweden all we had tp produce were our
>   passports, the completed application form with the passport sized pics
>   and the money for the visa. In fact it all went very smoothly.

Answer (score 3):

You can also send it back to an agent in the US, such as [US-China Chamber of Commerce](http://www.usccc.og) to do the visa as long as your passport shows that you are not inside China, i.e., exit stamps.

Using a reliable agent will eliminate a lot of uncertainties, and you do not need to take days off.  Also, in theory, you are supposed to get the visa from a Consulate in the country which you come from though US citizens do get visas outside the US.  However, you need to take the shipping cost into consideration.

This could cost between *US$60* and *US$100*.